# How to run a safe, responsible, fast MySQL backup

Tags: backup, mysql, replication

I've been tasked with assorted maintenance of a DB. I have very little experience with MySQL, so pardon any ignorance :)

Two (well, four) related questions:

1. The DB is supposed to be replicated to a backup slave, but it's been pointing at the wrong host for quite some time, so it's currently months behind. It looks like I want to run [`change master to`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/change-master-to.html) from the slave to fix this.

   - Is it generally safe to do this live?
   - If not, is there a static config counterpart to the command, such that I can send it out in a managed deployment?
2. We suspect the binary logs on the master may be corrupt/incomplete.

   - Will this affect the ability to fully replicate all data?
   - If so, how *can* I ensure a full backup? Is a full `mysqldump` overnight avoidable?

Hopefully I'm not barking up the wrong tree here. Feel free to point me in a different direction. The overall need is to have **a** backup, of some sort, as soon as possible. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a overnight backup is in order to get a baseline backup state is in order you can then address the log problem and start backing it up nightly there affer

Answer (score 0):

serverfault.com may be a better place to ask this.

Comment: Ack, you're right. I'm always confusing these two in my head. Any friendly mods care to migrate? I don't believe I can do so myself.